# Java can't do declarations?

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, xml

I read a blogpost [Dynamic Languages Strike Back](http://steve-yegge.blogspot.com/2008/05/dynamic-languages-strike-back.html) that claimed

> Why was The Ruby on Rails faster than Struts? This started one of the internet's largest flamewars... It was because they were serializing everything to and from XML because Java can't do declarations.

Can anyone explain what is meant by "Java can't do declarations" and how this relates to having to serialize everything to and from XML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe whats meant in this context is that Java does not allow [declarative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Declarative_programming) programming.

Answer (score 0):

This may refer to Java not being able to programatically create new objects at runtime. According to this, in RoR, values are passed directly into methods from (and returned to) an XML resource file without declaring a new instance of the class every time.

Comment: It can create new objects just fine (how is it supposed to get anything done without any objects?). You may be thinking of creating new classes/interfaces/etc. at runtime.

Comment: Derp. You're right. I meant to refer to calling class methods without instantiating objects. I believe Amir answered the question most correctly.